# Where should i put my php script for ajax implementation in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to implement ajax on a page .  i create a folder under plugins and put php page there and it works(when i gave the correct path in jquery). But when i try to call any WordPress functions it gives me error .

I want to do some database fetching in that file . How and where should i put the php file for simple ajax implementation ?

Comment: Thanks . If i need it only on the client side ,  is there any other preffered way ?

Comment: WP handles all ajax requests through `admin-ajax.php`. The fact that it considers the script to be running in the 'admin' bears no relation to the origin of the request, or even if the user is logged in.